# Having problems accessing full value from a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I stored 3 values in a dictionary:

```
gunStats = ("M4", 30, "AR")
PrimaryGun["Primary"] = gunStats
```

This works super well but now I am trying to access all 3 of the stats stored by doing this:

```
for values in PrimaryGun:
    statsOfGun = values
OldPrimaryGun["Old Primary"] = values
```

This only returns one of the stats.

Also if there are any tips on how to do this better please help me out, its to equip a gun by using values from another dictionary and inputing them into another dictionary!

Comment: It's rather odd that you have dictionaries who's variable names are also repeated in their keys. That seems like an unnecessary redundancy. Consider getting rid of the dictionary and just using the variable to refer to the tuple directly! I can tell your loop isn't doing anything useful (it only iterates over the keys in the dictionary), but I have no idea what you really want. Would `OldPrimaryGun = PrimaryGun` do what you need?

Comment: When you iterate over a dictionary, you are iterating over the keys and not the values. So, values will have the last key - "Primary".

Comment: @blckknght Im still trying to figure out the whole dictionary thing but can I really just set one dictionary = to another? I was using dictionaries to store multiple types of guns that the person using the program can create, its called Storage, I decided to use dictionaries to help make it easy transfering the variables between Storage and things like Loadout (Which is another dictionary which stores the names of the  primary, secondary and utility) and PrimaryStats (which I use to store the stats of the primary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the keys, not the values. In your code, `for values in PrimaryGun:` loops over the keys, e.g. `"Primary"`, not the stats. To do that, you need to loop over `PrimaryGun.values()`. Here is some code that may help make it clear.

```
guns = [("M4", 30, "AR"),
               ("M14", 20, "SA"),
               ("M16", 20, "CM"),
               ("AR15", 20, "AR")]
positions = ["Primary",
             "Secondary",
             "Tertiary",
             "Quaternary"]
gunStats = dict((zip(positions, guns)))

print(gunStats)

# returns:
# {'Primary': ('M4', 30, 'AR'),
# 'Secondary': ('M14', 20, 'SA'),
# 'Tertiary': ('M16', 20, 'CM'),
# 'Quaternary': ('AR15', 20, 'AR')}

for gun_stat in gunStats.values():
    statsOfGun = gun_stat
    print(statsOfGun)

# returns:
# ('M4', 30, 'AR')
# ('M14', 20, 'SA')
# ('M16', 20, 'CM')
# ('AR15', 20, 'AR')

for gun_stat in gunStats.values():
    rifle, rounds, manufacturer = gun_stat
    print(f'The {rifle} holds {rounds} rounds and its manufacturer initials are {manufacturer}')

# returns:
# the M4 holds 30 rounds and its manufacturer initials are AR
# the M14 holds 20 rounds and its manufacturer initials are SA
# the M16 holds 20 rounds and its manufacturer initials are CM
# the AR15 holds 20 rounds and its manufacturer initials are AR

for gun_info in gunStats.items():
    position, gun_stat = gun_info
    rifle, rounds, manufacturer = gun_stat
    print(f'The {rifle} holds {rounds} rounds, its manufacturer initials are {manufacturer}, '
          f'and it is the {position} gun in my collection.')

# returns:
# The M4 holds 30 rounds, its manufacturer initials are AR, and it is the Primary gun in my collection.
# The M14 holds 20 rounds, its manufacturer initials are SA, and it is the Secondary gun in my collection.
# The M16 holds 20 rounds, its manufacturer initials are CM, and it is the Tertiary gun in my collection.
# The AR15 holds 20 rounds, its manufacturer initials are AR, and it is the Quaternary gun in my collection.
```

In a situation like this, I would possibly use namedtuples to avoid having to unpack the values in order to use them.

```
from collections import namedtuple

GunStat = namedtuple('GunStat', 'rifle, rounds, manufacturer')

guns = [GunStat("M4", 30, "AR"),
        GunStat("M14", 20, "SA"),
        GunStat("M16", 20, "CM"),
        GunStat("AR15", 20, "AR")]
positions = ["Primary",
             "Secondary",
             "Tertiary",
             "Quaternary"]
gunStats = dict((zip(positions, guns)))

print(gunStats)

# returns:
# {'Primary': GunStat(rifle='M4', rounds=30, manufacturer='AR'),
# 'Secondary': GunStat(rifle='M14', rounds=20, manufacturer='SA'),
# 'Tertiary': GunStat(rifle='M16', rounds=20, manufacturer='CM'),
# 'Quaternary': GunStat(rifle='AR15', rounds=20, manufacturer='AR')}


for gun_stat in gunStats.values():
    statsOfGun = gun_stat
    print(statsOfGun)

# returns:
# GunStat(rifle='M4', rounds=30, manufacturer='AR')
# GunStat(rifle='M14', rounds=20, manufacturer='SA')
# GunStat(rifle='M16', rounds=20, manufacturer='CM')
# GunStat(rifle='AR15', rounds=20, manufacturer='AR')

for gun_stat in gunStats.values():
    print(f'The {gun_stat.rifle} holds {gun_stat.rounds} rounds and its '
          f'manufacturer initials are {gun_stat.manufacturer}')

# returns:
# the M4 holds 30 rounds and its manufacturer initials are AR
# the M14 holds 20 rounds and its manufacturer initials are SA
# the M16 holds 20 rounds and its manufacturer initials are CM
# the AR15 holds 20 rounds and its manufacturer initials are AR
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude this is amazing, I am just trying to get back into python and Im really enjoying it, this helps so much.

Answer (score -1):

When you loop over a dictionary like

```
for x in Dict
```

You are looping over all of the *keys* in the dictionary. To loop over the values of a dictionary, call a for loop over `Dict.values()` like so:

```
for x in Dict.values():
    do_stuff()
```

So your code turns into

```
for values in PrimaryGun.values():
    statsOfGun = values
```